# Can't get git to stop outputting to StdErr

Tags: git, tfs

I am working on some build scripts that get run on TFS. During the build process I need to check in the changes that where done during the build process (A set of binaries other projects depend on).

I would really like to leave the option "Fail on Standard Error" enabled for the script, however my push keeps writing to standard error even though I told it not to.

The line I do is:

```
git push -q binaryRepo HEAD:"$Env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH"
```

But I get the following in my log after the build

```
2016-10-28T20:05:32.3179442Z ##[error]remote: 
remote: Analyzing objects... (3/3) (657 ms)        
remote: Storing packfile... done (40 ms)        
remote: Storing index... done (42 ms)        

2016-10-28T20:05:32.3209423Z Done
2016-10-28T20:05:32.4019436Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.
2016-10-28T20:05:32.4029436Z ##[debug]System.Exception: Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.
```

Why am I still getting output to standard error when I included the `-q` switch?

---

If it matters `git version` reports `2.10.0.windows.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything prefixed with `remote:` is spit out not by *your* Git, but rather by the *other* Git, the one you're pushing-to.

There's no built-in way to shut up the other Git.  You could find out what sort of pre-receive and update hook they<sup>1</sup> have set up—these hooks, or the things they invoke, are what are printing `Analyzing objects` and so on—and see if they have provided a "quiet" flag, and if so, whether they have *also* provided some way for you to *set* that flag.<sup>2</sup>  If not, you are stuck: you must either discard stderr output entirely, or ignore it (which amount to the same thing).  You can trust that if *your* Git prints some important failure message, it will exit with a nonzero status: that's something you can control (by fixing your own Git if necessary, or switching to another version), while "things done on the remote" are generally something you cannot control.

---

<sup>1</sup>It sounds like "they" are in fact you, which means you're in luck!  Just stand over on the other, server, side, where you're doing these scripts, and see footnote 2.

<sup>2</sup>Due to a lack of exposed side channels, there's no easy and convenient, yet universal, way to set flags.  If you're using `ssh://` as your protocol, you can use `$HOME/.ssh/environment` to pass extra environment variables, *provided that **their** sshd permits this*. That's a bit clumsy, and obviously does not work at all if you are using `https://`.

Another method that will work in theory—I've never tried it in practice—is to have an agreed-upon, always-force-push-able, dummy branch or tag name.  This cannot be used with an `update` hook, but a `pre-receive` hook could scan athrough all the proposed updates, and if the special branch or tag is included, use its presence and/or its target object to provide the smuggled data (e.g., flags for the remaining pre-receive branch actions).

Comment: "They" is a online visualstudio.com git repository. I got a response from the git mailing list too saying pretty much the same thing but they also had a similar error in their arcives and it was visualstudio.com git server's fault. I have filed a bug report with visual studio.

Comment: Microsoft has fixed their implementation on their git server: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3109654/git-host-on-visualstudio-com-does-not-respect-the-q-flag-for-pushes